# How to read string from .properties file in junit-tests?

Tags: java, junit, wicket

I use wicket in my webapplication. I save the Strings in some .properties files as follows:

foo.properties

```
page.label=dummy
```

In the html-file, I can acces the String `page.label` as follows:

index.html

```
<wicket:message key="page.label">Default label</wicket:message>
```

Now I wrote some junit test cases for my Application and would like to access the Strings saved in the properties file. My Question is, how to read the String from the properties file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream("foo.properties"));
    Object label = p.get("page.label");
    System.out.println(label);
  }
}
```

This section allow you to read all properties files from wherever you want and load them in the Properties

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainClass {

    private static String PROPERTIES_FILES_PATHNAME = "file:///Users/ftam/Downloads/test/";// for mac

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Properties p = new Properties();

        List<File> files = getFiles();
        for(File file : files) {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            p.load(input);
        }

        String label = (String) p.get("page.label");
        System.out.println(label);
    }

    private static List<File> getFiles() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<File>();

        URL[] url = { new URL(PROPERTIES_FILES_PATHNAME) };
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url);
        URL[] urls = loader.getURLs();

        File fileMetaInf = new File(urls[0].toURI());
        File[] files = fileMetaInf.listFiles();
        for(File file : files) {
            if(!file.isDirectory() && file.getName().endsWith(".properties")) {
                filesList.add(file);
            }
        }

        return filesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Festado: Thanks for answering. What about if i have 100 different .properties files?

Comment: I'll try to update my post in few minutes so that you can use it in case of 100 files or more

Comment: Update is finished. Have fun

Comment: This might be the correct answer, but Wicket has it special search algorithm for properties reflecting the component tree. See the javadoc on http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/ComponentStringResourceLoader.html

Answer (score 2):

Wicket has its own way of localizing the resource, taking into account the component tree. See [the javadoc for the StringResourceLoader](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/ComponentStringResourceLoader.html).

One way of loading the Resource would be:

```
WicketTester tester = new WicketTester(new MyApplication());
tester.startPage(MyPage.class);
Localizer localizer = tester.getApplication().getResourceSettings()
                            .getLocalizer();
String foo = localizer.getString("page.label",tester.getLastRenderedPage(), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Properties_files) is a pretty good choice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) and then `get("page.label")`

Answer (score 0):

Have this field inside your class:

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

private static ResourceBundle settings = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test",Locale.getDefault());
```

then a `test.properties` file like this:

```
com.some.name=someValueHere
```

Finally you can access the property values this way:

```
private String fieldName = settings.getString("com.some.name");
```